# What are reasons the PHP function 'sem_release' might block?

Tags: php, semaphore

In a very complex php code I have isolated a problem with the function `sem_release` which is called to release a semaphore. However, this call to `sem_release` seems to be blocked for at least 100 seconds.

Are there any reasons why this function is blocking? I only can think about valid reasons a function `sem_acquire` can block when trying to **acquire** a semaphore. But why should **releasing** a semaphore block code execution?

Comment: Can you show the isolated problem as a code example?

Comment: I wish I could, but currently I am not able to isolate this problem.

Comment: I had a look at the PHP source code. The PHP extension itself performs no actions which could lead to the problem. It just calls the libc function `semop()`. You should have a look at [`man 2 semop`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop) therefore.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for this information, I will have a look at `semop` operation...